# How can I refer the objcet that calls a method in the method in Java?

Tags: java

I have the below code

```
User u1 = new User()
User u2 = new User()

u1.addUser(u2)
```

How can I refer to the object u1 in method addUser?  Below is the code of class User

```
public class User{
    private ArrayList<User> users;
    public void addUser(User a){
         users.add(a);
         // Here I want to do the opposite. 
    }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html

Comment: you can use this keyword.

Comment: `a.users.add(this)`.